# I am getting the SELECT mysql value in tuple form. How can I get it in string form?

Tags: python, mysql

```
mycursor.execute("SELECT Name FROM employee_details")
names =  (mycursor.fetchall())
for y in names:
    print (y)
```

**Result:**

```
('dsf',)
('Gai',)
('egw',)
('qwr',)
('Sam',)
```

**Result I want:**

```
dsf
Gai
egw
qwr
Sam
```

Answer (score 3):

`cursor.fetchall()` return list of tuples. you can access single values from tuple using index.

```
for y in names:
    print (y[0])
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a comma after the loop value in the `for` statement, to assign a name to the element in the tuple, and omit the comma when printing, to get only the element:

```
for y, in names:
    print(y)
```

As @deadshot mentions in the comments, this works because of Python's tuple-unpacking syntax.  It's no different to

```
a, b = (1, 2)
```

except that there is a single-element tuple involved, and we tend to think of tuples as having more than one element

```
a, = (1,)
```

Comment: Interesting. Where is this behaviour documented? Why it works?

Comment: @KacperWikieł tuple unapcking

Answer (score -1):

You can save result to string and replace ('') with " ". This is easy way to do it :D.

```
String = result.replace("('", "")
String = String.replace("')", " ")
```

Comment: result is not a string how can you use replace?